# How do i replace a value in a string for a csvfile without the use of imports?

Tags: python

I am not allowed any type of imports to do this question, so i am am very confused on how i can achieve the desired output.

The desired output:

```
Argentina,ARG,Feb 18 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 19 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 20 2020,0
```

The current output i have (was required to produce this):

```
Argentina,ARG,"Feb 18, 2020",0

Feb 18 2020

Argentina,ARG,"Feb 19, 2020",0

Feb 19 2020 

Argentina,ARG,"Feb 20, 2020",0

Feb 20 2020 

Argentina,ARG,"Feb 21, 2020",0

Feb 21 2020

Argentina,ARG,"Feb 22, 2020",0

Feb 22 2020
```

Some lines from the original CSV file:

```
Entity,Code,Date,Daily tests per thousand people (7-day smoothed) (tests per thousand)

    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 18, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 19, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 20, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 21, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 22, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 23, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 24, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 25, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 26, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 27, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 28, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Feb 29, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Mar 1, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Mar 2, 2020",0
    
    Argentina,ARG,"Mar 3, 2020",0
```

My current code for my current output:

```
N=5

with open(DATA) as file:

    next(file)

    for i in range(N):
        line = next(file).strip().split(",")
        print(",".join(line))
        print(line[2].replace('"',''),line[3].replace('"',''))
```

I am not sure how I will be able to derive the desired output. Any hints?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68825215/edit) with your code indented correctly.

Comment: try change your `for`-loop to one-liner: `with open(DATA) as f:

    for line in f:
        print(line.replace("\"", ""))`

Comment: I think you need to explain what the criteria for extracting the output. In your sample, the source data has 16 lines including the header, but your desired output only shows 3 lines. Is there a range of dates you are interested in?

Comment: I believe using your existing code, making the assumption that the fields are always going to be as you expect them to be, the print statement could be:
`print(line[0], line[1], line[2].replace('"', '') + ' ' + line[3].replace('"', ''), line[3], sep=',')`

Comment: I noticed you are new. If you find an answer that is useful remember to accept it. Further instructions are provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Glad to answer on your question. I have read your question and I suggested you to use Python pandas to read csv file.

So, we can modify the code as below :

```
with open("test.csv") as fn:

for line in fn:
    print(line.replace("\"", ""))
```

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: "I am not allowed any type of imports to do this question" can't use pandas

Comment: Okay. I will check it and find other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
f = open("file.csv", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
count = 0
for line in lines:
    if count != 0: #skip the header line
        x = line.split("\"")
        if len(x) == 3:
            print(x[0].lstrip() + x[1].replace(",", "") + x[2])
    count += 1
```

I get the following output:

```
Argentina,ARG,Feb 18 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 19 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 20 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 21 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 22 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 23 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 24 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 25 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 26 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 27 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 28 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Feb 29 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Mar 1 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Mar 2 2020,0

Argentina,ARG,Mar 3 2020,0
```

Comment: hey why would u split by backslash? could you explain that part? thank you so much

Comment: the backslash is to escape the " character so that you split by the " character, not the backslash.
This article has a longer explaination: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have all the details, but here are my assumptions:

1. You are skipping the header, which is the first line in the file.
2. Although your example output only had three lines, I'm assuming you want all lines processed.
3. In addition, the only change appears to be related to the quotation marks and removal of commas only within the quoted expression.
4. The quotation marks are always balanced (i.e., no solo double quotation marks)

```py
with open(DATA) as fd:
    header = True
    for inl in fd:
        inl = inl.rstrip()  # Remove trailing newline
        if header: # Skip first line
            header = False
            continue
        # Parse each line, part-by-part
        parts = []
        while inl:
            if inl.startswith('"'):
                part, _, inl = inl[1:].partition('",')
                if part.endswith('"'):  # In the case where line ends with "
                    part.rstrip('"')
                part = part.replace(',', '')
            else:
                part, _, inl = inl.partition(',')
            parts.append(part)
        print(','.join(parts))
```